# Player character won't go in front of buildings

Tags: game-maker, gml, game-maker-studio-2

Ok, so I managed to get all the buildings to stay in place, but now for some reason, the player character won't go in front of the buildings.

I tried switching the places in the code where the if the command for checking if the character's going behind the building and the if-else for checking if it's going in front of the code, but nothing changed.

here's the code:

```
var _dg = depth_grid;
var _inst_num = instance_number(obj_depth_buildings);

//below is for resizing the grid

ds_grid_resize(depth_grid,2, _inst_num);

//below adds instance info to grid

var _yy = 0;

with (obj_depth_buildings)
{
    _dg[# 0,_yy] = id;
    _dg[# 1,_yy] = y;
    _yy++;
}

//below sorts the grid so that the ones with the biggest y variables end up at the top
ds_grid_sort(_dg,1,false);

//below goes through the grid and identifies everything
var _inst;
_yy = 0;

repeat (_inst_num)
{   
    //below pulls out an id

    _inst = _dg[# 0, _yy];

    //below gets the instance execute depth

    with(_inst)
    {
        _inst.depth= layer_get_depth("collision") + _yy;

        with (obj_nonbuilding_depths)
        {
            if object_index.y > _inst.y
            {
                object_index.depth = (_inst.depth + 1);
            }
            else if object_index.y <= _inst.y
            {
                object_index.depth = (_inst.depth - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    _yy++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change the object depth by change the leyar depth in GMS2